# How to print a number in Python that is not another number?

Tags: python

Ok so I am writing a code that generates a random number like this

```
import random
randomNumber = random.randrange(1,4)
```

How can I make Python print a number between that range of (1, 4) that WILL NEVER print the same number as the "random number" variable? For example say the randomNumber chooses the number 3. I want a second randomNumber picker to print either 1 or 2. How can I make this possible?

Comment: Do you want to avoid repeating _only_ the first number, or avoid repeating any number that gets returned.

Comment: My code is going to look like this randomNumber=random.randrange(1,4) userChoice=raw_input("Pick 1, 2, or 3") then I want to print the number that is not the same as userChoice or randomNumber. Lets call this variable "not"

Answer (score 3):

To select `k` items from the list, use [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
import random
x = range(1,4)
print(random.sample(x, k))
```

---

If you want all the items from the range(1,4),
[shuffle it](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle), and then just iterate through the shuffled list:

```
import random
x = list(range(1,4))   # list is for Python3 compatibility
random.shuffle(x)    
print(x)
# [2, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to randomly return numbers in a certain range without ever repeating any number, you can use `random.shuffle` as in unutbu's answer.

If you want to exclude only certain items (like just the first) from being repeated, you can use a `set` and `random.sample`:

```
x = set(range(1,4))
r = random.sample(x, 1)
x.remove(r)  # we should never return r again

# these two calls might return the same number (but not r)
random.sample(x, 1)
random.sample(x, 1)
```

---

Responding to your comment:

> My code is going to look like this randomNumber=random.randrange(1,4) userChoice=raw_input("Pick 1, 2, or 3") then I want to print the number that is not the same as userChoice or randomNumber. Lets call this variable "not"

Try:

```
randomNumber = random.randrange(1, 4) 
userChoice = raw_input("Pick 1, 2, or 3")
s = set([1,2,3]) - set([randomNumber, userChoice])
notPicked = random.sample(s, 1)[0]  # this returns a one-element list, so [0] gets that one value
```

Comment: Well I that is ok if they do pick the same number as the rand.randrange then that means the notPicked variable will just get to choose between 2 numbers now (or at least that is what I want to happen)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obtain random values from a range and not repeating previous values, then you can use `random.choice` on each iteration, then pop out the item from range and repeat again.

```
import random
seq = range(1, 4)

while len(seq) > 0:
    ret = random.choice(seq)
    seq.pop(seq.index(ret)) # pop result
    print(ret)
```